# knockout.js validation plugin not working with CakePHP

Tags: javascript, cakephp, knockout.js

I'm trying to use the [knockout.js validation plugin](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) with CakePHP but I can't seem to get it working.

I'm including the validation plugin at the end of the corresponding view. The network tab in Chrome shows it loading properly, however, any reference to the validation plugin throws an error.

For example, on my page that contains my viewmodel(named EntryViewModel), I have the following code

```
function EntryViewModel(){
  //viewmodel code here
}

EntryViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(EntryViewModel);
```

Here is the error

```
'Uncaught type error: cannot call method 'group' of type undefined'
```

Am I referencing it incorrectly? At the end of my CakePHP view I include the knockout.validation file and it shows properly loaded in the network tab

Comment: Give us the full JavaScript context.  What order are your script tags in?  The CakePHP stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: @BradKoch I've switched the order multiple times and it still gives the same error. What do you mean by the javascript context? Why would whats inside the viewmodel matter? Also, the viewmodel has several hundred lines of code.

Comment: I mean the order your script tags are in.  ko.validation is undefined, so it must not have been loaded successfully when the above code was executed.  Since you've verified the browser loaded the file, it's either an execution order problem or an assignment problem.  Thus the importance of seeing the script tag order.  Don't expand `//viewmodel code here`, that's not useful.

Comment: Also, if you comment that errant line out, let the page load without error, and in the JS Console verify that ko.validation is defined, it's definitely an execution order problem.

Comment: @BradKoch The order is knockout.js, orders.js (the file containing MVVM), knockout.valitation.js

Comment: There's at least one problem right there.  The order must be knockout.js, knockout.validations.js, orders.js; you can't use a library before it's loaded.  Get that step done first and add the information to your question.  If that doesn't work, we'll continue from there.

Comment: @BradKoch that was the error. Thanks for the help! However, now I have a question about formatting the error message. I'll post a link to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EntryViewModel` is trying to use knockout validations, but it hasn't been loaded at that point in the execution order.  You can't use a library before it's loaded, so make sure the order is correct.  Example:

```
<script src="knockout.js"></script>
<script src="knockout.validations.js"></script>
<script src="orders.js"></script>
```